# C++ about Intel PCM source code #ifndef INTELPCM_API #define INTELPCM_API #endif

Tags: c++, class

I'm reading the IntlePCM source code.
in cpucounters.h, I'am confused of these statements.

```
#ifndef INTELPCM_API
#define INTELPCM_API
#endif 

class INTELPCM_API PCM
{
 ...
}
```

what's the role of INTELPCM_API? 
it seems to be a decoration for class PCM, but i don't understand this and the keywords to google solutions for that.

thanks a lot!

Kerr

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at the Makefile used to build this.  Defining the value of that symbol on the compilation command line would have the effect of "cutting and pasting" that value between the keyword "class" and "PCM".  If you were to find some actual value being placed there, it might shed some light on what they are trying to accomplish.

As an alternative to slogging through the Makefile, you can tell the compiler to stop after preprocessing (before compilation).  With gcc for example, this is done with the -E flag, try:

```
    gcc -E cpucounters.h > somefile.txt
```

The contents of somefile.txt will contain the C code, but after the preprocessor has done its magic.  This will show what is actually being passed to the compiler, and might be easier to decode.

Comment: Thanks, @BarryGackle I tried and got this:`class INTELPCM_API PCM`->`class PCM`. It seems that INTELPCM_API actually  means nothing... But it deed affected when i tried to use boost.python to expose class PCM.